# Box shadow bottom like bracket

Tags: html, css, border, box-shadow

I am trying to implement bracket at bottom of a div. here my shadow will be like bracket .
I tried below section. Bur problem is it's taking full left right section. I want like this image. any suggestion will be appreciable.

[image]

```css
div{
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
 box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
 height:100px;
  }
```

```html
<div>wefwefwef</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gradient for this:

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  padding:3px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,blue 3px,transparent 0px,transparent calc(100% - 2px),blue 0) 0 100%/ 100% 30px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to top,blue 2px,transparent 0);
}
```

```html
<div>wefwefwef</div>
```

Or a pseudo element like this:

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  padding:3px;
  position:relative;
}
div:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height:20px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  border:2px solid blue;
  border-top:none;
}
```

```html
<div>wefwefwef</div>
```

Or border-image with gradient:

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  padding:3px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 60%,blue 0) 10;
}
```

```html
<div>wefwefwef</div>
```

Comment: I used border-image with gradient. tx.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the `:before` and `:after` *pseudo-elements*:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
  height: 100px;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px; /* adjust */
  height: 10px; /* adjust */
  background: #de1dde;
}

div:before {
  left: 0;
}

div:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>wefwefwef</div>
```